# What are these aircraft at the Naval Air Weapons Station China Lake?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification, us-navy

What are these 12 aircraft at the co-ordinates [35.677323, -117.676903](https://www.google.com/maps/place/35%C2%B040'38.4%22N+117%C2%B040'36.9%22W/@35.677284,-117.6771075,147m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d35.677323!4d-117.676903)?

I recognize the F-111 and C-130, but not the others.

[image]
<sup>Source: google maps</sup>

Comment: Are you asking about the Naval Air Weapons Station - China Lake?

Comment: There is no C-130 in the photo - I'm looking at the upper right as the suspect. A 130: (1) its fuselage does not taper in the back. (2) its fuselage is proportionally wider (3) its wing is high-mounted, it hides that part of the fuselage as seen from the top.(4) its engine nacelles are more streamlined, being a turbine. Those in the photo look like radial piston to me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This answer is a [Community Wiki](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki).
Community edits are welcome.

---

The aircraft in the photo appear to be the following, or varients therof:

1. [Douglas R4D-8 (Super DC-3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_C-47_Skytrain#Super_DC-3_.28R4D-8.29)

[image: R4D-8 at China Lake]

<sup>[source](http://www.air-and-space.com/Douglas%20DC-3%20History%2070s-80s.htm), photographer: Brian Lockett</sup>

2. [North American T-39 Sabreliner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Sabreliner)
3. [Boeing C-97 Stratofreighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_C-97_Stratofreighter?wprov=sfla1) or [KC-97](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_KC-97_Stratofreighter) tanker varient
4. [McDonnell Douglas F-4 Phantom II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F-4_Phantom_II)

[image: F-4 at China Lake]

<sup>[source](http://www.air-and-space.com/20020624%20China%20Lake%20vintage%20aircraft.htm), photographer: Brian Lockett</sup>

5. [Vought F-8 Crusader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vought_F-8_Crusader)
6. [North American T-39 Sabreliner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Sabreliner)
7. [North American RA-5C Vigilante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_A-5_Vigilante) <sub>[tail number 156640](https://books.google.com/books?id=BJ4Q_TPoXgMC&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=tail%20number%20156640%20us%20saratoga&source=bl&ots=H2Jd-ev20c&sig=ibgVoBnG2M7rqQanzSirvmyfPkU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6-8q8vY_QAhXiw1QKHbRIBAMQ6AEICjAA#v=onepage&q=tail%20number%20156640%20us%20saratoga&f=false)</sub>

[image: RA-5C]

<sup>[source](http://www.air-and-space.com/20020624%20China%20Lake%20vintage%20aircraft.htm), photographer: Brian Lockett</sup>

8. [Boeing B-29 Superfortress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-29_Superfortress)

[image: B-29]

<sup>[source](http://www.air-and-space.com/20020624%20China%20Lake%20vintage%20aircraft.htm), photographer: Brian Lockett</sup>

9. [General Dynamics F-111B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dynamics%E2%80%93Grumman_F-111B) <sub>[tail number 152715](http://f-111.net/t_no_B.htm)</sub>

[image: F-111]

<sup>[source](http://www.air-and-space.com/20020624%20China%20Lake%20vintage%20aircraft.htm), photographer: Brian Lockett</sup>

10. [Grumann A-6 Intruder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_A-6_Intruder)
11. [Douglas R4D-8 (Super DC-3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_C-47_Skytrain#Super_DC-3_.28R4D-8.29)
12. [Grumann A-6 Intruder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_A-6_Intruder)

No C-130 appears in the photo included in the question, though one may appear elsewhere near the coordinates linked.

Notes:

- `1` and `11` are not C-47 Skytrain. They are longer and have a square tail which is typically for the Super DC3 / R4D-8
- `3` is longer from the wing root to the nose than the same measurement on `8`, supporting that `3` is not a B-29.
  Moreover, in the photo of `7`,  aircraft `3` appears in the background which clearly shows engine nacelles like those of the B-50 or C-97 series.
  The same photo shows a fuselage rising higher above the wing than a B-50, which is consistent with a C-97 variant.
- `5` measures nearer the 54 ft in length of an F-8, versus the 46 ft in length of an F-7, supporting that it is an F-8

Comment: 3 looks more like the B-50 and 8 looks like the B-29

Comment: 7 looks like a model of an early VFX/VFAX prototype; what would become the F-14. While swing-wing for speed and space, and dual-tail for maneuverability and stability, were both the vogue at the time, Grumman had designs for single-tail and fixed-wing variants of the VFX fighter carried forward from the doomed F-111B project.

Comment: 10 and 12 are definitely A-6's by the way. You can make out the fixed probe on the left side of the cockpit, and the fuselage and strake lines are a dead giveaway.

Comment: @KeithS on bing maps it looks like it has one vertical stabilizer and I found a photo of the remains of an F 111B at China Lake. It seems to me that this is an 111B.

Comment: @KeithS you can edit this answer to add that info, if you would like

Comment: Good job on finding the ground photos

Comment: @DeltaLima - I actually don't think so. The F-111B was always going to be swing-wing like its Air Force counterpart, and the design also has leading-edge strakes over the top of the intakes and a fatter nose due to the side-by-side seating arrangement. Compare #7 to #9; that is absolutely 100% an F-111.

Comment: @KeithS Are you suggesting that `7` is an F-111? I think we have definitive evidence that `9` is an F-111B. I'm losing track of everyone's antecedents.

Comment: @KeithS In his book, [California Warplanes](https://books.google.com/books?id=BJ4Q_TPoXgMC&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=tail+number+156640+us+saratoga&source=bl&ots=H2Jd-ev20c&sig=ibgVoBnG2M7rqQanzSirvmyfPkU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6-8q8vY_QAhXiw1QKHbRIBAMQ6AEICjAA#v=onepage&q=tail%20number%20156640%20us%20saratoga&f=false), Harold Skaarup cites tail number 156640 (`7` here) as an RA-5C.

Comment: @KeithS I now see your comment was related to no.7. Since you mentioned the F-111 I automatically thought you were talking about no. 9. Sorry for the confusion I created

Answer (score 2):

1,11- [Douglas C-47 Skytrain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_C-47_Skytrain)

2,6- [North American Sabreliner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Sabreliner)

3,8 - [B-29 Superfortress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-29_Superfortress)

4- [McDonnel Douglas F-4 Phantom II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F-4_Phantom_II)

5- [Vought A-7 Corsair II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTV_A-7_Corsair_II)

7- [North American Vigilante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_A-5_Vigilante)

9- [General Dynamics F111 Aardvark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dynamics_F-111_Aardvark)

10,12- [Grumman A-6 Intruder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_A-6_Intruder)

Comment: 1 and 11 are not C-47 Skytrain. They are longer and have a square tail which is typically for the Super DC3 or R4D-8

Comment: 9 is an F-14 Tomcat. Note the single piece canopy vs. the Aardvark's split canopy, as well as the dual vertical stabilizers (the Aardvark only has one).

Comment: @SnakeDoc I only see one vertical stabilizer on `9`. The intakes on `9` also do not match the F-14. I think this answer is correct on this being an F-111.

Comment: `3` is not a B-29, but a B-50.

Comment: @SnakeDoc The aircraft is definitely an F-111. The Tomcat has very pronounced intakes where the wings meet the fuselage. The F-111 does not. If it were an F-14, you would see two "shoulders" for the intakes just behind the canopy. The F-111's intakes are underneath the wings, not in front like the Tomcat.

Comment: What is the B29 a plane of the Air Force and Army Aviation doing in **Naval** Air Weapons Station?

Answer (score 0):

1. Douglas DC-3/C-47
2. North American T-39 SaberLiner
3. Boeing KC-97
4. McDonnell Douglas F-4
5. Vought F8U/RF8U Crusader
6. North American T-39 SaberLiner
7. North American A-5/RA-5 Vigilante
8. Either a Boeing B-29 or a B-50 Superfortress
9. General Dynamics F-111 Aardvark
10. Either a Grumman A-6 or a KA-6 Intruder.
11. Douglas DC-3/C-47
12. Either a Grumman A-6 or a KA-6 Intruder.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm 7 is a North American A3J - A-5 - RA5 Vigilante. Looks a lot like a hot, 1960s fighter, a F-14, MiG-25, or F-15. I've read that Soviet espionage delivered enough A3J information that TsAGI based the MiG-25 shape on it. That's slightly odd, the A3J was a supersonic bomber with a deterrence role, like TSR-2. But Navy requirements included max weight catapult launches from an ANCHORED aircraft carrier. Deterrence means ready to go, 24/7. This was when the USAF had nuclear-armed bombers airborne, 24/7.